# what is the function that convert a word of type string to an object with keys an the index of the character?

Tags: arrays, object, split, type-conversion

is there any function that can convert for us a string to an object like this format

```
{"0":"F","1":"a","2":"t","3":"i","4":"m","5":"a","6":" ","7":"m","8":"a","9":"y","10":"c","11":"h","12":"i","13":"n","14":"e","15":" "}
```

Comment: Which language are you using? It's not mentioned.

Comment: language is javascript

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate() from python:

```py
string = "Hello World"
enum = enumerate(string)
print(dict(enum))
```

This should get you:

```py
{0: 'H', 1: 'e', 2: 'l', 3: 'l', 4: 'o', 5: ' ', 6: 'W', 7: 'o', 8: 'r', 9: 'l', 10: 'd'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a problem implementing this function yourself, you can use the following approach in `Javascript`:

```
var s = "Hello World";
var dic = {};
for(var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
  dic[i] = s[i];
}
console.log(dic);
```

Output:

```
{0: 'H', 1: 'e', 2: 'l', 3: 'l', 4: 'o', 5: ' ', 6: 'W', 7: 'o', 8: 'r', 9: 'l', 10: 'd'}
```